# Repeating module name for each module component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, naming-conventions, code-organization, project-structure

The famous [Best Practice Recommendations for Angular App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) blog post outlines the new recommended angularjs project structure which is now component-oriented, not functionally-oriented, or as named in the [initial github issue](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/109) - "Organized by Feature".

The blogpost suggests that each file inside each module should start with the module name, e.g.:

```
userlogin/
    userlogin.js
    userlogin.css                
    userlogin.html                
    userlogin-directive.js
    userlogin-directive_test.js
    userlogin-service.js
    userlogin-service_test.js
```

The question is: what is the point, pros and cons of repeating the module name inside each filename in the module as opposed to having the files named functionally? For example:

```
userlogin/
    userlogin.js
    userlogin.css                
    userlogin.html   
    controllers.js             
    directives.js
    services.js
```

---

The reason I ask is that I'm coming from a [`Django`](https://www.djangoproject.com/) world where there is a somewhat similar idea of having [projects and apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/). Each app usually has it's own `models.py`, `views.py`, `urls.py`, `tests.py`. There is no repeating app name inside the script names.

I hope I'm not crossing an opinion-based line and there is a legitimate reason for following the approach.

Comment: Repeating the name of the component in the file name is very helpful, when having multiple tabs (files) opened in your IDE. In most IDEs the title of a tab is the name of the opened file. Just by looking at the tab's title you can immediately deduce what component is the file part of. Without repeating the name you can easily end up having opened multiple tabs with the same title and navigating through the project gets a bit complicated and error-prone.

Comment: I Also am a Django+ Angular user and i dont put the module name in the filenames. My personal opinion is that it creates a sense of cleanliness in the project and helps when revisiting a code I didnt work for some time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a very good reason and it is for improving a very important aspect for any non-trivial codebase (especially when large teams of developers are involved), namely what we call "overviewability".

"Overviewability" is the ability of the codebase's organzation (folder structure, file naming, meta-objects etc) to provide a quick and informative overview of the implemented software.

The "overviewability's" significance increases exponentially with the size of the codebase and that of the developers team working on the project* for the following reasons (non-exhaustive list):

1. When a codebase is large, the probability of certain parts of the code to be left untouched for a specific time period increases (as increases the duration of this "cold" period).
2. When new members join the team, you want them to be brought up to speed as soon as possible (and not get them frustrated in the process). "Overviewability" helps provide a good high-level abstraction of the whole project and usually also gives a good sense of how things work (more often than not it creates a feeling of familiarity; it's as if you've seen the codebase before - although you haven't).

---

*"So, OK, "overviewability" is important. That's why we have this nice, component-centric structure etc. But **why** prefixing each file with the component's name ?"*

Well, it might sound funny, but prefixing all component-related filenames ensures a specific order. E.g. the HTML partial or the CSS will always appear before the controllers etc:

```
...               
userlogin.html                
userlogin-controller.js
...
```

Where it not for the prefix, you would end up with various orders depending on the name of the component. E.g.:

```
...                       ...                      ...
controller.js             controller.js            bookself.html
...                       ...                      ...
service.js         VS     service.js        VS     controller.js
...                       ...                      ...
userlogin.html            zombi.html               service.js
...                       ...                      ...
```

Using a prefix ensures the files appear in specific order: controller comes always after the HTML partial, service also etc. E.g.:

```
...                             ...                         ...
userlogin.html                  zombi.html                  bookself.html
...                             ...                         ...
userlogin-controller.js    VS   zombi-controller.js    VS   bookself-controller.js
...                             ...                         ...
userlogin-service.js            zombi-service.js            bookself-service.js
...                             ...                         ...
```

This might seem trivial, but it's not; especially as one gets used to it.
Note that the human mind is very good at recognizing visual patterns (like the ones created by a tree-node representation of the folder- and file-structure in a file-explorer).

I.e. the controllers do not reside in *a file named "<component>-controllers.js"*.
It resides in *the first file whose name is significantly longer than the previous files*.
The service (if any) resides in *the file with the smaller name at the end*, etc.

Mess that up (i.e. mess the order up because of the starting letter or mess their relative lengths up because of long/short component names) and you have yourself a situation similar to having to read something from the hard-drive, instead of just reading it from the RAM. (No developer wants to go there :))

---

<sub>*: Actually, it's what we call the "dev team flux" that is important here, i.e. how often a team member will leave (e.g. to work on something else, leaving the company etc) or a new member will be introduced.

   Usually, the larger the team, the greater the flux.</sub>

Comment: Wow, haven't thought about it that way. Totally makes sense, thank you very much!

Comment: **human mind is very good at recognizing visual patterns** -- very well put!

Comment: There is a follow-up to this question: [Project organization and naming conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769920/project-organization-and-naming-conventions) - would really appreciate your insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

### **It's all about organizing large Projects (code base):**

---

> I've found names and folder-hierarchies to be very valuable for
>   organizing large projects. Similarly, meaningful, hierarchical names
>   help me tremendously.

Coming from the ***ASP.NET*** world, where projects are huge, we have:

***Solutions*** -> managing ***Projects*** (assemblies) -> with ***folders*** -> and ***sub-folders***, for ***files***.

So an ***ASP.NET MVC*** Project will have a ***Home*** Controller in the `Controllers` Folder of the ***MVC Presentation Project***, and `Views` in the ***Views*** Folder.

---

When using ***AngularJS*** in my projects, I like the approach of naming

```
App(Module)-type(directive/service)-(sometimes more detail)
```

This is in addition to naming *folders for apps*, and having ***directives*** and ***services*** in folders for their types with the folder named after the ***app*** and the app often named functionally or after the ***ASP.NET View*** (like my View may be `Account-Login`).

All this because my projects are very very big. I end up having many ***AngularJS*** `apps`, crazy number of `directives`, and even fair number of `services`.

When your project is small or even medium size, the advantages are arguable. But when your project grows big, organization is critical! Both to help you find the code you need, and to continue propagating more.

Comment: I hate .NET projects that end having many NameOfTheModuleController inside the same folder. Same for views. I try to always use Areas where I can put each controller inside a different folder.

Comment: @LGama, I agree with both sentiments. Enterprise projects never stop growing. It's not just their intended size, or eventual size. You end up managing absurd amounts of code. Redundant naming has the advantage of minimizing misunderstandings -- I'd hate to have multiple data services without distinguishing what they apply to.

Comment: There is a follow-up to this question: [Project organization and naming conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769920/project-organization-and-naming-conventions) - would really appreciate your insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

***tl;dr;* While the other answers aren't wrong in most of their points, they fail to recognize the importance of the file navigation tools available today to developers.**

---

## Navigating Project Files Quickly

Once we are fairly well acquainted with a project, we will want to navigate between files without looking at the source tree. Our naming scheme will play an important part in allowing us to navigate quickly. We can navigate to a file extremely quickly by entering fragments of the file name. For example, if your module's name is `forsee` you can see a list of `forsee` *javascript* files by typing `fo.js` in a file search box (assuming your editor has this feature). The *Chrome Dev Tools* Source tab has this feature built-in. You can see it in action, **[here](http://www.chevrolet.com/camaro-performance-cars.html)** (open the dev tools and press *Cmd+O*):

[image: Fragment Search Screenshot 1]

I used to think that prepending all file names with the module name was necessary to search effectively, but then realized that isn't true at all. We can just as effectively search for `fo/js`:

[image: Fragment Search Screenshot 2]

So now it should be clear that **we can just as quickly navigate to a file regardless of whether or not the module name is prepended to the filename**.

---

## Overviewability

I agree with ExpertSystem that grouping files together allows you to see things better at a glance. However, once again prepending the module name isn't really necessary. Rather, activate the appropriate option in your editor:

[image: Sort by Type Screenshot]

In the screenshot above, I activated the *Sort by Type* option to enable sorting files by their file extensions.

---

## Why We Shouldn't

If coding on a small screen (ie., laptop) and using a left-hand rail tree view to navigate the folder structure, the limited screen real estate will be better served by shorter file names. The module folder name will be visible so it's not useful to see that name repeated for every file.

---

## Caveats

Obviously, most of what I presented above does rely on developers using the right tools and knowing how to use them well. If your team does not have these tools or you doubt their ability to use them effectively, train them, or stick with the extra-verbose naming scheme.

---

## Conclusion

With the advanced tools available to developers today, repeating the module name for every file is anachronistic. However, overly verbose file naming doesn't cause any great harm or efficiency problems. When structuring a new project, there are many other architectural decisions we'll have to make that are far more important than this one.

---

<sub>BTW: I do name **js** files according to ExpertSystems suggestion. Ie., `dialog.js`, `dialog-ctrl.js`, `dialog-services.js`, etc. This makes sense for the reasons he stated, but when a module has multiple partials it's best not to follow this naming pattern for **html** files.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much! Really glad there is a different opinion presented. Most of us use sublime and webstorm, and we are still debating about the naming.

Comment: Regarding organization (tangentially related) [check out my sass guide](https://github.com/gilbox/futuristic-sass-guide). I'm not crazy about putting *css* files alongside *javascript* files because I think it encourages CSS code that is less re-usable across modules. That is, I think that CSS modules and application modules should be treated like two separate things.

Comment: There is a follow-up to this question: [Project organization and naming conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769920/project-organization-and-naming-conventions) - would really appreciate your insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about this in one of my [blog posts](http://gigablox.com/articles/building-large-angularjs-applications)

#### Modules often have overlapping features

Let’s say were building an account settings page. The *admin* account can `sendNotifications` where the *user* account  can `updateNotifications`. Both *admin* and *user* accounts can `updateAvatar`.

#### Describes features as well as relationships

*Components abstracted into separate modules, files, and folders are easier to work with.*

A parent that encompasses all of these modules could be called *account*. We know that *account* will have two different **roles** and three different **features**. If *account* was "role agnostic", your definition might look something like:

```
angular.module("account",  [
  "account.updateAvatar",
  "account.sendNotifications", 
  "account.updateNotifications"
]);
```

But defining parent modules to these features promotes organization and inheritance:

```
angular.module("account",  [
  "account.common",
  "account.admin", 
  "account.user"
]);

angular.module("account.common",  [
"account.common.updateAvatar"
]);

angular.module("account.admin",  [
"account.admin.sendNotifications"
]);

angular.module("account.user",  [
"account.user.updateNotifications"
]);
```

Feature modules can follow a similar pattern:

```
angular.module("account.common.updateAvatar",  [ 
"account.common.updateAvatar.services",  
"account.common.updateAvatar.controllers",  
"account.common.updateAvatar.directives",
"account.common.updateAvatar.filters"
]);
```

Views and assets:

```
account.common.updateAvatar.less
account.common.updateAvatar.tpl.html
account.common.updateAvatar.heading.tpl.html
account.common.updateAvatar.body.tpl.html
```

#### Dot notation can enable easy globbing patterns

Compile all of your HTML partials into cached JavaScript:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    html2js: {   
      partials: {
        src: ["src/**/*.tpl.html"],
        dest: "build/js/app.tpls.js",
        module: "app.tpls"
      }
    }
  )};
};
```

Concat all of your *admin* JavaScript independent of your *user* JavaScript:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      admin: {
        src: ["src/**/*.admin.*.js"],
        dest: "build/js/admin.js"
      },
      user: {
        src: ["src/**/*.user.*.js"],
        dest: "build/js/user.js"
      }
  )};
};
```

Comment: There is a follow-up to this question: [Project organization and naming conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769920/project-organization-and-naming-conventions) - would really appreciate your insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As ExpertSystem stated, your current directory structure is not in relation to the blog  [Best Practice Recommendations for Angular App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub).

I am in conjunction with ExpertSystems as well as Gil Birman, that the approach in order to design the app structure should be modular. As you know that Angular itself follows a modular structure so whether you have multiple modules or a single Angular module you need to think according to the functionality you catering to. For instance if you have a 'CountDown' functionality it should have its own structure.

### Why this is important?

**1. Code Maintenance:** As your code will grow your maintenance costs grows. If for instance in the production environment you get an error in your angular code and want to rectify with a KRA of 1 hour, you would first need to replicate the scenario locally and then traverse to that particular file. If it had been module you would know which folder to target and boom you got the solution fast.

**2. Development Ease:** You can split multiple functionalities between multiple developers and they can target different functional folders so their wont be touching the same files. Merging conflicts can be reduced.

**3. Faster Reviews:** Since the app is broken down into functionality, reviews can be done faster and with ease knowing that the code for that folder is for that particular functionality.

**4. TDD Implementation:** The structure can be used to kick start Test Driven Development (TDD). Benefits of TDD are mentioned over here in this [article](http://www.base36.com/2012/07/benefits-of-test-driven-development/)

### Difference between Development and Production Code/Structure

In Development you can have the structure according to the functionality. However in order to improve on the performance of your web application (or a hybrid mobile app), the best way to go about that is to concatenate all the files, minify it and obfuscate it using [GRUNT](http://gruntjs.com/). Will be giving a sample of the GRUNT file for the same. You can run the script every time during deployment using any continuous integration tool such as Jenkins for example.