# Project organization and naming conventions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, naming-conventions

This is somewhat a follow-up to [Repeating module name for each module component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005897/repeating-module-name-for-each-module-component) question.

We've decided to follow the suggested in [Best Practice Recommendations for Angular App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) blog post angular project organization and naming conventions while building a small internal application for measuring connection quality.

And this is what we've got at the moment:

```
$ tree -L 1
.
├── app-config-service.js
├── app-config-service_test.js
├── app-connection-service.js
├── app-connection-service_test.js
├── app-controller.js
├── app-controller_test.js
├── app-countdown-directive.js
├── app-countdown-directive_test.js
├── app-footer-directive.js
├── app-footer-directive_test.js
├── app-footer-service.js
├── app-footer-service_test.js
├── app-math-service.js
├── app-math-service_test.js
├── app-stats-directive.js
├── app-stats-directive_test.js
├── app-status-directive.js
├── app-status-directive_test.js
├── app-status-service.js
├── app-status-service_test.js
├── app-time-directive.js
├── app-time-directive_test.js
├── app.css
├── app.js
├── bower_components
├── config.json
├── countdown.html
├── footer.html
├── img
├── index.html
├── ping
├── stats.html
└── status.html
```

As you can see, there are several directives, services, partials, single controller, module declaration file and couple config and app-specific unrelated to the topic files. This really becomes a mess of files and is not quite readable and easy to work with.

This is probably because *we have only one single module* and keep everything inside it.

Is it okay to use the good old component-oriented approach and have special directories for `services`, `controllers`, `directives` and `partials` for such a simple app? Does this mean that the new "Organized by feature" approach work only for non-trivial huge applications?

Comment: Checkout this style guide... https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#application-structure

Comment: @AnthonyChu thank you, it is a good one too. I've probably read too many guides and it is time to follow common sense more than guides :)

Comment: Same city, but different universes. In **ASP.NET** Projects (often Enterprise, often huge), we use folders excessively. In fact we hierarchically stack folders. **Views->Admin**, **Views->Reports**, etc. So you have **Components->Functionality** is our paradigm. You could just as well reverse it. Point is you need a way to organize code by Functionality AND Feature. Call it "Overviewability", heck, call it a subway map. The need isn't obvious until you run into a pile-up of files.

Comment: @DaveA thank you for the opinion. I guess I can interpret this as "do whatever fits the needs of a particular app taking into account it's size and complexity". This is somewhat similar question to the one you've helped me with, but this time we've got a real app and we are trying to develop a convention inside the team - got confused again. I guess this always would be opinion-based and project-specific, no silver bullet out there.

Comment: Definitely aim toward a scheme that flows with your teams operrating style, code to date, and as much as you can project. Teams and team members develop monackers and associations that work for them. I do agree, that rather than asking for best practices, you spend some serious time analyzing the growth direction and cluster forms your team trends toward, and design a convention that works with their tendencies. Many approaches could work, but only a couple would work well with your teams flow and tendancies. Try to emphasize what they do well and structure where they float in wrong directions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say that you decided to *"follow the suggested in [Best Practice Recommendations for Angular App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) blog post"*, but you don't seem to have followed it...

---

According to the recommended approach, each component/feature should be in its own directory (under a `components` directory).

For the reasons pointed out by [Gil Birman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769920/project-organization-and-naming-conventions#answer-25778519) and also detailed in the aforementioned [blog post](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) as well as in [Repeating module name for each module component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005897/repeating-module-name-for-each-module-component), it makes more sense to organize the directories by feature (e.g. the `foo`-feature directory contains all directives, services, controllers, partials etc related to that feature) than organizing by type (e.g. all controllers in one directory, all services in another) etc.

---

In any case, all the above are guidelines (more a way of thinking) and not a precise recipe or a deterministic algorithm that can decide for you where to place each file (e.g. is there going to be a `components/lib/` directory, will a service go inside a feature's directory or under a `components/common/` directory etc).
You need to understand the guidelines (and what purpose/need the are trying to fulfil) and develop a convention that suits your team's style.

There are times when you won't be sure where to place a file. You can have a debate with the team, make a decision and go with that.
This is totally normal (especially at first), but you'll find out that as time goes by, such cases will arise more and more rarely.

---

That said, I would expect your directory and file structure to be more like that (making some assumptions about which services might be more generic/utility-like):

```
app/
|___ app.css
|___ app.js
|___ app-controller.js
|___ app-controller_test.js
|___ bower_components
|___ config.json
|___ index.html
|
|___ components/
|    |___ common/ or util/
|    |    |___ config-service.js
|    |    |___ config-service_test.js
|    |    |___ connection-service.js
|    |    |___ connection-service_test.js
|    |    |___ math-service.js
|    |    |___ math-service_test.js
|    |
|    |___ countdown/
|    |    |___ countdown.html
|    |    |___ countdown-directive.js
|    |    |___ countdown-directive_test.js
|    | 
|    |___ footer/
|    |    |___ footer.html
|    |    |___ footer-directive.js
|    |    |___ footer-directive_test.js
|    |    |___ footer-service.js
|    |    |___ footer-service_test.js
|    |
|    |___ img/
|    |    |___ ...
|    |
|    |___ stats/
|    |    |___ stats.html
|    |    |___ stats-directive.js
|    |    |___ stats-directive_test.js
|    | 
|    |___ status/
|    |    |___ status.html
|    |    |___ status-directive.js
|    |    |___ status-directive_test.js
|    |    |___ status-service.js
|    |    |___ status-service_test.js
|    |
|    |___ time/
|         |___ time-directive.js
|         |___ time-directive_test.js
|
|___ misc/
     |___ ping
```

Comment: This is a very detailed answer, thank you very much for the help. You are right about that the reason we have a pile of files now is that we haven't split the app into components (angular modules). It is actually due to the application grow - it looked very small at the beginning, couple services and directives, but, as time went by, more and more things showed up. Then, we looked at this, thought about dividing it into smaller angular modules, but decided that, for example, footer is too small to be a separate module. Your points totally make sense to me.

Comment: And, yes, I also like the point that footer can just be placed into a "footer" directory under components - it is not required to make an angular module out of it.

Comment: @alecxe: Just making sure it is clear: a directory inside `components/` doesn't necessarily have to include and angular module (one defined using `angular.module(..., [...]);`. From the blog post: _"Components may contain module definitions, if appropriate. [...] Module definition can happen in the main module file, or in subdirectories for sections or components, depending on the application's needs."_ So, if a component is small it doesn't have to be a separate module - putting it into it's own directory is separation enough.

Comment: @alecxe: I posted my last comment before seeing your last comment, so I guess everything was clear enough in the first place :)

Comment: Things are much clear now, thank you, I'll keep the topic open for a while due to bounty periods :)

Answer (score 2):

### Modular architecture mimics how our brain works

Even for a small project, I would still separate the project into *module* folders for the simple reason that it makes **it easier to find the code you need to work on.** That's because us programmers generally work on a per-module basis.

For example, for an hour we will work on the footer module which includes both directives and services which will reside in the `footer` dir. In contrast, it's much less likely that we will decide that for an hour we have to work on various directives in the directives folder and never touch any service.

### Modular architecture makes it easier to rip code across projects

When I start a new project, regardless of the size of that project I usually start by ripping modules out of existing projects. With modular architecture this is extremely easy and intuitive.

Of course, if a module is highly reusable you should package it as a bower module instead, but most small modules will end up being customized on a per-project basis.

Comment: This is what I was worried about. We have another app growing, that really strictly follows modular architecture style - we have auth module, that has login, change_password, forgot_password etc angular modules inside, footer and header are splitted into separate modules too. Here, at the beginning, we thought that the app is really very small and footer, for example, is too tiny to be a module. But, I see now that it can really help to organize things better. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For the beginning I recommend sticking with project organization offered by **yeoman** generators:
http://yeoman.io/

It uses **component-oriented** approach; and offers multiple generators that will put code in expected location, generate **unit tests** for them, keep **file-names patter**, set up the **grunt build** description etc.

The example project structure looks like this:

[image]

Definitely it's worth to use a structure approach to even simple application. The will be plenty of possibilities to create a mess in the code base, so better start neatly:) The problem can arrive on the other end of the scale - at same point you may need more then just **one module**, and standard yeoman generator doesn't support it well.

Answer (score 1):

As ExpertSystem stated, your current directory structure is not in relation to the blog  [Best Practice Recommendations for Angular App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub).

I am in conjunction with ExpertSystems as well as Gil Birman, that the approach in order to design the app structure should be modular. As you know that Angular itself follows a modular structure so whether you have multiple modules or a single Angular module you need to think according to the functionality you catering to. For instance if you have a 'CountDown' functionality it should have its own structure.

### Why this is important?

**1. Code Maintenance:** As your code will grow your maintenance costs grows. If for instance in the production environment you get an error in your angular code and want to rectify with a KRA of 1 hour, you would first need to replicate the scenario locally and then traverse to that particular file. If it had been module you would know which folder to target and boom you got the solution fast.

**2. Development Ease:** You can split multiple functionalities between multiple developers and they can target different functional folders so their wont be touching the same files. Merging conflicts can be reduced.

**3. Faster Reviews:** Since the app is broken down into functionality, reviews can be done faster and with ease knowing that the code for that folder is for that particular functionality.

**4. TDD Implementation:** The structure can be used to kick start Test Driven Development (TDD). Benefits of TDD are mentioned over here in this [article](http://www.base36.com/2012/07/benefits-of-test-driven-development/)

### Difference between Development and Production Code/Structure

In Development you can have the structure according to the functionality. However in order to improve on the performance of your web application (or a hybrid mobile app), the best way to go about that is to concatenate all the files, minify it and obfuscate it using [GRUNT](http://gruntjs.com/). Will be giving a sample of the GRUNT file for the same. You can run the script every time during deployment using any continuous integration tool such as Jenkins for example.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer organize my project in feature(module) based approach on top level and type based (directives, controllers) on lower levels:

[image]

in this example i have 3 separated (root) modules home, search and shared. These modules are root parts of my application. Each module may contain directives, services, views, less files, etc. In general I prefer to keep related parts of my application as close as i can. That is way i grouped each parts of the news directive in the news folder. But keep in mind that this news directive is used only in my home module. If it would be used in multiple modules (home and search) then i will move the news folder into the shared folder.

This is similar approach to prefix based approach from this question ([Repeating module name for each module component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25005897/repeating-module-name-for-each-module-component)) but I use folders instead of prefixes.

Comment: Yup, having prefix is still something I cannot really believe in. Inside the team we are still arguing whether to prefix files, or just having them inside submodules is enough. Thank you for the example!

Answer (score 0):

When you start a project, there is not only the file structure to have in mind. I would recommend you to think about how to create your modules and how you want to inject the dependancies, and ofcourse how you want to minify your application.

Angular boilerplate at github.com is a boilerplate project which let you build the application with grunt, use bower for depandancies, live reload your browser and lets you use LESS instead of CSS.

It contains a starting structucre like this:

```
ng-boilerplate/
|- grunt-tasks/
|- karma/
|- src/
|  |- app/
|  |  |- <app logic>
|  |- assets/
|  |  |- <static files>
|  |- common/
|  |  |- <reusable code>
|  |- less/
|  |  |- main.less
|- vendor/
|  |- angular-bootstrap/
|  |- bootstrap/
|  |- placeholders/
|- .bowerrc
|- bower.json
|- build.config.js
|- Gruntfile.js
|- module.prefix
|- module.suffix
|- package.json
```

It also contains guide on how to set it all up. Happy hacking!

https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp